# simple_cycles produces output in non-deterministic order?

Tags: python, networkx

I noticed that the output of NetworkX `simple_cycles` algorithm may not be deterministic, in the sense that same cycles in the same graph may be detected in a different order when an algorithm is run multiple times. Or the same cycle may be detected with nodes in the cycle not being in the same order all the time.

Is this expected behavior of the algorithm? I glanced through the source code and I don't see any randomization elements in the order of execution/etc.

If it's not to be expected, I'm wondering if there is something that messes up my graph in the background.

Comment: What version of networkx?  What version of Python?  Are you doing *any* modification of the graph in between? My best guess is that it might have something to do with Python dicts not having a guaranteed order.

Comment: Thanks Joel. NX version 2.3 on Python 3.x with Anaconda.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior in some [very simple] graphs I've made.  Are you able to give an example that might reproduce it?